# Validate form fields and write to database on successful completion

Tags: php, jquery, html

I wrote a little script with jQuery. With this script you can get more "steps" if you click on the button "einen Schritt hinzufügen".

Now when I press the button "erstellen", I want to check if all the fields are filled and if successful, write the data into a database.

How can I connect PHP with jQuery, after jQuery validation of the fields is completed?

Here is the example page:

[MyPage](http://localhost/Design_neu/index.php?content=create_tutorial)

And here is the code (without CSS):

```html
<section>
    <article>
        <div class="step">
            <div class="header_step">Erstelle dein eigenes Tutorial</div>
            <div class="body_step">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="index.php?content=create_tutorial">
        <div class="step">
            <div class="header_step">Allgemeines zum Tutorial</div>
            <div class="body_step">
                <a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Tutorial's</a><input class="create_tutorial_input"/>
                <br>
                <a class="create_tutorial_a">Autor des Tutorial's</a><input class="create_tutorial_input"/>
                <br><br>
                <a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Schrittes</a>
                <br>
                <textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="all_steps">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="step">
            <div class="body_step">
                <button class="create_button" type="submit" name="submit">Erstellen</button>
                <input type="button" class="create_button" id="add_step" value="Schritt hinzufügen"/>
                <input type="button" class="create_button" id="remove_step" value="Schritt entfernen"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        
    </article>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</section>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".all_steps"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#add_step"); //Add button ID
    var remove_step     = $("#remove_step");
    
    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(){ //on add input button click
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="step"><div class="header_step">Schritt '+ (x + 1) +' des Tutorial\'s</div><div class="body_step"><a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Schrittes</a><input name="input_title_name'+x+'" class="create_tutorial_input" /><br><a class="create_tutorial_a">Bild</a><input type="file" /><br><br><a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Schrittes</a><br><textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_description_name'+x+'"></textarea></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
    });
   
    $(remove_step).click(function(){ //user click on remove text
        $('.all_steps .step:last').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Re-worded the sentences and title to better explain the problem. Technology/library names (like PHP, jQuery) are not required in the title because they can be added as part of tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), because without AJAX, you cannot have the right access to connect with your server.

Here a simple example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "url",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
       alert("success")
    }
})
```

`type` is method, and `data`the params you want to send in your databases. 
Hope you understand it!

Comment: nope, i dont understand. But i need Ajax for this? Then i will show some tutorials.^^

Comment: Yeah, you need ajax to connect with you server! :)

Comment: on question to the expiry. First i press some times the button "schritt hinzufügen" then i get some more field. After that i fill the fields, then i press the button "erstellen". I use jquery to check the fields? And then i use ajax to put the data into my database?

Comment: Yeah, you send the filled input to send to data to your server! :)